# SQL Query output: Insert a row, based on a fields value

Tags: sql, insert, row, toad

I'm busy whit some SQl query's that are processed by excel and that printed using a word serial letter. This is to make a delivery note for Fruit at school. 80 Children means 80 portions of fruit and this fits into one crate. So for more than 80 children we need 2 crates and so on. The maximum at this point will be 240 children, so 3 crates. Making the calculation is no problem, but making the extra line is. Last year I did it static in excel but this year there are more schools so more data. Therefore I want only one place to change it and this would be the SQL database.

The data looks like this:

```
Customer     Children
ABC             240
DEF             37
GHI             90
```

And it should look like this in the output:

```
Customer     Children    Crates
ABC             240        3  
ABC             240        3
ABC             240        3
DEF             37         1
GHI             90         2
GHI             90         2
```

I don't want the extra rows in the database, only on the output in excel (or other program like Toad).

For testing I use Toad for SQL and that I import the query into excel 2010 via PowerPivot.

Comment: Do you want a sql query that will return the expected result?

Comment: Yes, so that in the result window are more lines than in the SQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using recursive CTE:

```
with    cte(customer,children,crates,i) as 
        (
        Select customer,children, children/80 + case when children%80 = 0 then 0 else 1 end crates, 0 from test
        union all
        select  customer,children,crates
        ,       i + 1
        from    cte
        where   cte.i < cte.crates -1
        )
select  customer,children,crates
from    cte
order by customer
```

Live example using your test data: [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0e84d/7)

Result from SQLFiddle:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I get the message that something is wrong near the 'With' keyword.

Comment: Which database are you using? Try adding semicolon ; before with.

Comment: This is on a MS-SQL server 2000. now i get: Wrong syntax near ';',

Comment: I am guessing your database is Oracle. Since cte are introduced in 11gR2 you may be getting because of that. If you are using previous version of oracle you can use connect by instead of CTE

Comment: It is SQL 200, and I found indeed that CTE is not supported. Also found a workaround whit a temporary table, but I think that is also not an option. I wont risk writing into the database. Could it be done whit a full join?

Comment: CTE was introduced in SQL 2005. Temporary tables are written in temp DB actually; so you should not worry about it as they are dropped after the query execution. Also, I can think of using a cursor or a loop for doing this. I can't think of a way of doing it using only joins.

Comment: Yes, it's working. At least whit the SQL 2012 server were a copy of the 2000 database is made every day. So i simply use that copy.  Thanks

Comment: That is great!! It would definitely work on sql 2012.